# Weight distribution of a code

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

Let $A_i$ be the number of codewords in $C$ of weight $i$, with $1 \leq i \leq n$. We defined the list of $A_i$'s as the weight distribution of the code.

Now, let $C$ be an [n, k, d] code over $F_q$. If C is a binary code containing $1 = (1, ..., 1)$, why is then the weight distribution of C symmetric?

I began as follows that, if C is symmetric, it should hold that $A_i = A_{n-i}$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$. But until here, it's just using the definitions...how sould I proceed to show the claim?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the all-1 vector lies in the binary code, then for each codeword $c$,
$$c' = (1,\ldots,1) - c$$
is also a codeword with the property that the Hamming weight of $c'$ is $n$ minus the Hamming weight of $c$.

If $C$ is binary and self-orthogonal, then $0=\langle c,c\rangle = c_1^2+\ldots+c_n^2 = c_1+\ldots+c_n$ and so $c$ must be even.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But what if $C$ is binary again and self-orthogonal? I read that in this case, each codeword has even weight and that $C^\perp$ the codeword 1 = (1, ..., 1). Why?

Comment: Please see my added comment.

Comment: I don't understand what self-orthogonality has to do with the matter at hand. Much better if you expand your first sentence to say that for every codeword $c$ of weight $i$, there is a codeword of weight $n-i$ and so it must be that $A_i = A_{n-i}$ for all $i$.

Comment: @Dilip: see the comment of JohnD.